# Integer and Variable Values in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I was working on a linear algebra problem and a question came up for me: why can't a variable have two values at once? It was a simple system of 3 equations in two unknowns:

x+y=2
x-y=1
x  =4

I substituted the value of x into the two equations at the top and found that y must equal -2 and 3 at the same time. Of course, I've been taught that a variable can only have one value at a time, but why is this? Why can't y have both of these values to satisfy both equations?

Comment: When this happens, we say the system of equations is "inconsistent".  That is, there is no solution; there is no value of $y$ that satisfies all the equations.

Comment: If you were to subsequently refer to the variable $~y,~$ how would the reader know which value of $~y~$ was being referred to?  The situation that you are referring to is handled somewhat differently by math writers.  For example, let $~r~$ be any root of the equation $~(x-1)(x-2) = x^2 - 3x + 2 = 0.~$ Let $~S~$ denote the set $~\{1,2\}.~$  Then, in a situation, where you want to specify that either $~r = 1~$ **or** $~r = 2,~$ you might (instead) specify that $~r~$ is **any** element in the set $~S.$

Answer (score 0):

When you write those three equations the intention is to find all the pairs of  numbers $(x,y)$ that make *all three* equations true *simultaneously*.

What your work shows is that there are no such pairs.

If you had the two equations
$$
x + y = 1 \text{ and } 2x = 2 - 2y
$$
there would be infinitely many solutions - pairs like $(1, 0)$ and $(5, -4)$ and so on.

You do not need to think about "variables" or "one value at a time" to understand this idea.